# link_to with double namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have routes defined like this:

```
 namespace :dealer, path: '' do
   resources :images, except: :index do
     resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy] do
       resources :attachments, only: :show
     end
   end
 end
```

In my view using `link_to url_for([@image, comment])` results in a url named:

`dealer_image_dealer_comment_path` which doesn't exist. It should be `dealer_image_comment_path`. Any way to avoid the double namespace?

I'm receiveing this error:

```
undefined method `dealer_image_dealer_comment_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb599499520>:0x007fb5994980d0>
Did you mean?  dealer_image_comments_path
               dealer_image_comment_path
```

rake routes:

```
dealer_image_comments POST      /images/:image_id/comments(.:format)                                                                   dealer/comments#create {:subdomain=>"dealer"}
dealer_image_comment DELETE    /images/:image_id/comments/:id(.:format)                                                               dealer/comments#destroy {:subdomain=>"dealer"}
```

Comment: Try adding member like `...resources :images, except: :index do
member do
        resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy] do.....`

Comment: Can you drop the output from `rake routes`?

Comment: @MaximFedotov question is updated

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon this changes the route names which im not trying to do!

Comment: As a rule of thumb it's not recommended to have more than 2 levels deep

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, with `link_to` you can do the following:

```
link_to "Comment", [@image, comment]
```

Take a look at [link_to UrlHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) for more information

Comment: I've tried that as well and the same result is produced

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own helper to accomplish this:

```
  def path_gen(namespace, models)
    path = ''
    models.compact!.each do |m|
      path = path + '_' + m.class.name.demodulize.downcase
    end
    send("#{namespace}#{path}_path", *models)
  end
```

which accepts `path_gen([@image, comment])`